# I can't understand why i have the wrong size of my array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

I have a problem with this C program. I don't understand why even though i initialized my array with a `malloc()` instruction, I am having the same size (4bytes) whatever is the second parameter i pass to my function initialize.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stack{
    int size;
    int *tab;
    int top;
} stack;

void initialize(stack* st, int sizeArray);
int pop(stack* stack);
void push(stack* stack, int number);


int main(){
    int sized;
    stack S;
    stack* ptr_S = &S;
    printf("Enter the size of your stack please: \n");
    scanf("%d", &sized);
    //We send the pointer of the stack to initialise
    initialize(ptr_S, sized);
    printf("%d\t%d", S.size, S.top);
    //printf("\nThe size of the array is: %d\n", sizeof(S.tab)/sizeof(int));
    printf("\nThe size of the array is: %d\n", sizeof(S.tab));
    pop(ptr_S);
    return 0;
}

void initialize(stack* st, int sizeArray){
    st->size = sizeArray;
    st->top = 0;
    st->tab = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * sizeArray);
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: The size of the array is `sizeof(int) * sized`; it has `sized` elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First of all, arrays are not pointers, ane vice-versa.**

On your code, `S.tab` is a pointer, and using `sizeof` on a pointer will evaluate to the size of the pointer itself, not the amount of allocated memory to that pointer.

On your platform, a pointer (`int *`) is having a size of 4 bytes, so you always see the output being 4.

In case, you have a properly null-terminated `char` array, you can use `strlen()` to get the length of the elements of the string, however, still that may not give you the *actual* size of the memory allocated, anyway. You need to keep track of the size yourself. Normally, you cannot expect to *extract* the information from the pointer itself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, could you now help me with the syntax i should use to get the good result? Because I actually agree it is a pointer but how using the unary (*) is not still resolving my problem.

Comment: @franckstifler which unary * you're talking about, please?

Comment: `strlen` *definitely* won't give you the allocated size, which is at least `strlen(...) + 1`.

Comment: Sorry for my english, I am not native english speaker. Just got confused in the `strlen()` is it not meant for Strings?. My program is meant to simulate stacks of integers with an array of integers. I wished my user should choose the size of the stack, and i allocate memory it on my pointer  `int* tab`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Right sir, that's why I mentioned about the size of the elements, not the memory. :)

Comment: @franckstifler Sorry, I still did not get you. Leave about the `strlen()` part, that was just an example. As far as memory allocation is concerned, it is good. Just don't try to retrieve the size from the pointer using `sizeof`. You need to make use of the `size` variable itself go get the size.

Comment: My code works. Although I could not get the size. I did some testing and it works smoothly.

Comment: @franckstifler That is what, allocation is fine, just don't expect `sizeof` will give you the size, it will not. That's all